# How can I determine whether or not a point is enclosed in a n-gon in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

Given a list of points in polygon_list, if I have a point A, how can I create a python function to determine whether or not this point is within the enclosed shape made by the values of polygon_list?

I also want to remain strictly in matplotlib and numpy (not shapely or anything like that).

Comment: Matplotlib is a plotting library, not a geometry library. It's not the right kind of tool for this.